# How do I remove the single quote being returned from a python string?

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7

The printing of my repr returns a ' (single quote) to the string.  The return can not have this, it must match exactly.

I've tried searching for a result on line and found several answers but when I attempted to apply the .split .replace etc I was unable to successfully get this to work.

```
class staff:

    def __init__(self,a,s=False,e=False):
        self.name = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return """{"New Employee": { "Name": %a } }""" % (self.name)

Name = '''"Bob"'''

print (repr(staff(Name)))
```

Current Output: `{"New Employee": { "Name": '"Bob"' } }`

Expected Output: `{"New Employee": { "Name": "Bob" } }`

Edit:

Name = "Bob"
Name = 'Bob'

Both give the result indicating 'Bob' I'm wanting the result of "Bob"

Comment: How many quotes, and what type, do you have around Bob? I count 5 single quotes on each side, or perhaps 2 double and a single quote.

Comment: When copy-pasted into a monospace font, it comes out as `'''"Bob"'''`: 3 single quotes, and one double quote, for each side. Hence, `Name` includes the double quotes together with Bob. Remove those double quotes, and your output will be as wanted.

Comment: Please always double check your formatting: a lot of the code in your question is *outside* the code block (and the part inside it, is only there because of Python's required indentation). That would have shown the actual problem immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Remove Quotes From String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564999/how-to-remove-quotes-from-string-in-python)

Comment: Current output: `ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 28`

Comment: To 9769953 - 

I got a Single quoted Bob when running the modification you mentioned.

class staff:
    
    def __init__(self,a,s=False,e=False):
        self.name = a
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return """{"New Employee": { "Name": %a } }""" % (self.name)


Name = '''Bob'''

print (repr(staff(Name)))
{"New Employee": { "Name": 'Bob' } }

Answer (score 0):

You give your staff-instance the name `'''"Bob"'''` - including `"` front and back - they are *part* of the given name.

You are essentially returning the repr of a dictionary ... change your code to:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr( {"New Employee": { "Name": self.name } } )
```

to get the *exact* representation of a dictionary.

If you want to remove `"` in front and back of `"Bob"` either do not give them in the first place or remove them:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr( {"New Employee": { "Name": self.name.strip('"') } } )
```

Comment: class staff:
    
    def __init__(self,a,s=False,e=False):
        self.name = a
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr( {"New Employee": { "Name": self.name } } )


Name = "Bob"

print (repr(staff(Name)))
{'New Employee': {'Name': 'Bob'}}

This is close, I am looking to get the result of double quotes through out.

Comment: class staff:
    
    def __init__(self,a,s=False,e=False):
        self.name = a
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr( {"New Employee": { "Name": self.name.strip('"') } } )


name = "bob is cool"

print (repr(staff(name)))
{'New Employee': {'Name': 'bob is cool'}}

Both results are very close to my expected result, both with single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @user Why double quotes? Are you trying to emulate json? PYthon uses `'` and `"` interchangeable - it prefers `'` and only uses `"` if your text contains `'` - i.e. `"Mac'n'Cheese"`.

Comment: I suppose this shows my lack of knowledge of how that works. My apologies after receiving your last reply,I tested the single quote output in the api I am working with and it worked.

All of the api documentation indicates double quotes around everything.

Thank you so much for your help!